# Python Group By multiple keys in an array of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, group-by

I have an array of dictionary like this in Python

```
{'district': u'd1', 'community': u'commu2', 'month': 8.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org1'}
{'district': u'd2', 'community': u'commu8', 'month': 9.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org2'}
{'district': u'd1', 'community': u'commu4', 'month': 9.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org1'}
{'district': u'd2', 'community': u'commu5', 'month': 8.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org2'}
{'district': u'd2', 'community': u'commu7', 'month': 9.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org2'}
{'district': u'd1', 'community': u'commu3', 'month': 9.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org1'}
{'district': u'd2', 'community': u'commu6', 'month': 8.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org2'}
{'district': u'd1', 'community': u'commu1', 'month': 8.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'organization': u'org1'}
```

How can i group by multiple key values, like (district, month, year, organization) and generate a denormalized list like this ?

```
{'district': u'd1', 'organization': u'org1', 'month': 8.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'community': ['commu1', 'commu2']}
{'district': u'd1', 'organization': u'org1', 'month': 9.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'community': ['commu3', 'commu4']}
{'district': u'd2', 'organization': u'org2', 'month': 9.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'community': ['commu5', 'commu6']}
{'district': u'd2', 'organization': u'org2', 'month': 8.0, 'county': u'c1', 'year': 2012.0, 'community': ['commu7', 'commu8']}
```

EDIT: My database TABLE columns of interest are

```
DISTRICT, COMMUNITY, DATE, ORGANIZATION, COMMUNITY
```

I am using Django's ORM to fetch data in the format 1 as above, but i really need data in format 2

My Django ORM fetch looks like this

```
list(ActivityReport.objects.all().
     values('date').\
    extra(select={'year': "EXTRACT(year FROM date)"}).\
    extra(select={'month': "EXTRACT(month FROM date)"}).\
     values('organization' ,'year','month', 'district', 'community'))
```

And my Django Model looks like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    community = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Comment: How big is the data set really, and are you married to the output format you have suggested? (Still a dict)

Comment: the data set would grow upto 10,000 rows, and I need to denormalize it to reduce data size. This is necessary as I'm passing it to the browser later on

Comment: Do you have control over how the original data set (normalized) is generated? If, for instance, you are getting it from a database that way, the best solution will be to generate it differently instead of trying to massage it in memory before passing it along.

Comment: Yes, I am getting it from the database. But I don't think i can fetch data in the second format directly from database. DJango's ORM only allows me to do aggregates like SUM,COUNT,AVG, etc. but getting one of the column data as a list, attached to other column data is not feasible i think.

Comment: I've added the table schema and the source of the first format data. Not sure if i can directly get data in format 2.

Comment: Let's back up a step. The real issue here is that you are retrieving data from a database in a format that is not ideal. Now that we know this has to do with Django, can you post the relevant models so we can suggest a better query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68438/discussion-between-noob-mama-and-two-bit-alchemist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68438/discussion-between-noob-mama-and-two-bit-alchemist), we know there are some additional constraints here: the data coming in is in this format, it is saved to the database as is, and the proposed solution is iterating over it to massage it during view processing before serving it to the user.

It would likely be better, performance-wise, if community were a foreign key relationship, to reflect that it is one-to-many, and as such this may not be the most scalable solution. Caveats out of the way, here is what I propose:

```
>>> # data is your original dict
>>> output = {}
>>> for row in data:
...   key = (row['month'], row['year'], row['district'], row['organization'])
...   if key in output:
...     output[key].append(row['community'])
...   else:
...     output[key] = [row['community']]
... 
>>> output
{(9.0, 2012.0, u'd1', u'org1'): [u'commu4', u'commu3'], (8.0, 2012.0, u'd2', u'org2'): [u'commu5', u'commu6'], (9.0, 2012.0, u'd2', u'org2'): [u'commu8', u'commu7'], (8.0, 2012.0, u'd1', u'org1'): [u'commu2', u'commu1']}
```

The idea here is to use the one-to-one data as a tuple, which is immutable and can thus serve as a dict key, and then create a mapping from that to the list of communities. If the mapping is already there, you append to the list, otherwise create it. After one pass, the data is as shown.

Hopefully this technique could be adapted to the real dataset or even to other lists if other one-to-many relationships are present.